# How do I get the Python UTC datetime in which hours, minutes, and seconds are all zeroes?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, utc

I'm using Python 3.8.  Is there a simpler way to get the current UTC time in which the hour, minute, and second are all zero?  For example, if UTC now evalutes to "2020-09-24 12:34:45", I would want my result to be "2020-09-24 00:00:00".  Right now I have

```
today = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
today_wo_time_str = datetime.datetime.strftime(today, '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')
today_wo_time_obj = datetime.datetime.stpftime(today_wo_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')
```

which seems a little unecessarily wordy.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace

Comment: `datetime.now(timezone.utc).replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)`

Comment: @MrFuppes, if you want to put that as the answer, I'll accept.

Comment: @Dave: I noted that my comment is basically the linked answer, only that I added UTC as time zone - so it's alright.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be get the current UTC datetime, as you are already doing, and then combine its date only component with a midnight time component, using the `combine()` function.

```
import datetime

utc_now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
midnight = datetime.time(0)
utc_midnight = datetime.datetime.combine(utc_now.date(), midnight)
print(utc_midnight)
```

This prints:

```
2020-09-24 00:00:00
```

Comment: this has two lines which aren't needed *and* uses [utcnow](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/11/utcnow.html) ;-)